# What does 'lay'd-on' mean in Camillo's speech (scene 3, act 5 of "The Winter's Tale")?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs, early-modern-english, shakespeare

In [act V, scene 3](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Shakespeare_-_First_Folio_facsimile_(1910)/The_Winters_Tale/Act_5_Scene_3), of *The Winter's Tale*, Hermione says:

> *Cam.* My Lord, your Sorrow was too sore **lay'd-on**,
> Which sixteene Winters cannot blow away,
> So many Summers dry: scarce any Ioy
> Did euer so long liue; no Sorrow,
> But kill'd it selfe much sooner.

I tried [to decode](https://www.shakespeareswords.com/Public/Play.aspx?Content=Text&WorkId=35&Act=5&Scene=3) the first verse of Camillo's speech but to no avail. I read it, *My Lord, your Sorrow was excessive,[...]*. I looked up
*lay on* [in Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lay_on), but methinks the verb does not mean *to say somethin repeatedly* here.

What does *lay'd-on* mean in Camillo's speech?

Comment: I'd go for the full OED's definition V-28-a (there are *plenty* to choose from! :) - **lay on**  *V. **To impose as a burden***. 28-a *To impose (a penalty, command, obligation, burden, tax, etc.).* First cited use (if you can make sense of it! :) **713** - *He mec of heofonum hider onsende, geseah þæt ge on eorðan fore æfstum on his wergengan wite legdon.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Oxford Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/lay-on#:%7E:text=lay%20on-,phrasal%20verb,take%20guests%20to%20the%20airport.) carries this sense of the multi-word verb 'lay on' (though OLD labels it currently 'informal', and some other dictionaries do not list this sense – only the narrower [but commoner] subsense involving a volitional agent: 'tell or show something to someone, especially when you do not expect them to like it' [[Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/lay-on)]
• *Okay, I’m ready for the bad news. Lay it on me.*):

> **lay something on somebody** [informal] to make somebody have to deal with something unpleasant or difficult
>
> - *Stop laying a guilt trip on me* (= *making me feel guilty*).

This definition allows the *natural cause* subject referent, doubtless by personification. This sense is paraphrased by 'forcibly applied [of a state]', so that 'your Sorrow was too sore lay'd-on' paraphrases to 'you were too severely afflicted by this tragedy [for you to be totally over it even after 16 years]'.